# Any difference in audio quality for various YouTube video resolutions?

Tags: youtube, audio

Some music videos on YouTube are available in more than one resolution.

Do they all have the same audio quality? Or do the videos with larger resolution have better audio?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wikipedia has a table with different conversions and also the audio related to them.

[image: YouTube Encoding Details]

**<sub>As of Jan 2013</sub>**

[Quality and codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_codecs)

I'm sure the sound quality might have to do a lot with flash player as well, but I'm no expert on that.

Comment: Whoa, now that's a definitive answer! Thanks @Muhammad and also @Barry who embedded the table! I'll mark this as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a detailed list for audio qualities for different video qualities (as Dan commented, this was true until 2013):

http://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/youtube-audio-quality-bitrate-240p-360p-480p-720p-1080p

```
---------------------------------------------
| <b>Resolution | Audio Bit Rate | Compression |
---------------------------------------------
| Original   | 192 kbps       | AAC         |
---------------------------------------------
| 1080p      | 192 kbps       | AAC         |
---------------------------------------------
| 720p       | 192 kbps       | AAC         |
---------------------------------------------
| 480p       | 128 kbps       | AAC         |
---------------------------------------------
| 360p       | 128 kbps       | AAC         |
---------------------------------------------
| 240p       | 64 kbps        | MP3         |
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

BalthaZar comment seems to be true until 2013 from what this article says : http://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/youtube-audio-quality-bitrate-240p-360p-480p-720p-1080p

Since then Youtube seems to be using a constant audio quality for 360p and higher. Lower than 360p isn't commented.

Fast answer: So higher than 360p isn't needed for listening to music.